# What is the parameter I'd need to use for "e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs"

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

I've taken over a project, and after sending an email, the details are supposed to be logged along with whether or not the email send was successful.

However, I noticed that the subroutine to log the data is never being called. So, I tried to include this in the bottom of the email send code like so

```
Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail) ' Here, Smtp_Server is System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
                         ' e_mail is System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

sendComplete(Me, New AsyncCompletedEventArgs)   ' This is the call for the log subroutine
```

However, the bottom line gives the error:

> 'Public Sub New()' is obsolete: 'This API supports the .NET framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code

This is the start of the `sendComplete` subroutine.

```
Public Sub sendComplete(ByVal sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)

Try
   If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
      PictureBox1.Visible = False
      MsgBox("Failed to send email!", MessageBoxIcon.Warning + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
      mailSent = True
```

What do I need to put into the second parameter to make the code call the subroutine? Or does the `sendComplete` subroutine itself need changing?

**EDIT**

After adding the following `Try...Catch` statement to the code, as suggested, the code executes fine and doesn't hit the `Catch`, however, after sending the message, doesn't go to the `sendComplete` subroutine.

```
Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(senderAdd, senderPass)
Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = False
Smtp_Server.Host = SMTPserver

Try
   AddHandler Smtp_Server.SendCompleted, AddressOf sendComplete
Catch ex As Exception
   silentErrorLog(ex)
End Try
```

Comment: Smtp_Server.Send is a synchronous call, but sendComplete seems to be expecting the result of an Asynchronous call. That's probably not what is expected.

Comment: @Slugsie, hmmm, so how can I call it in this case?

Comment: I don't think you should be calling it.  It looks like an event handler.  Somewhere you should probably have a line similar to this:  `AddHandler Smtp_Server.SendCompleted, AddressOf sendComplete`  When the `SendAsync` method completes, the event will be raised and the handler will run.  Also `Smtp_Server` is a poor variable name for an instance of the `SmtpClient` class!

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yeah, like I said, not my code, I've just had to make changes too it - That's on the previous dev!

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Hmmm, I added in the code you said (see edit) but it still isn't getting called?

Comment: Did you also change the code to call `Smtp_Server.SendAsync`?  That would have to happen _after_ the call to `AddHandler`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Ah, okay, noted. What is the second parameter required? I've replaced `Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)` with `Smtp_Server.SendAsync(e_mail, "")` for now, but in the `sendComplete` sub it's got the line `If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then`, where e is the second parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running into a similar issue myself, @ChrisDunaway's comments have actually proved to be very helpful. My emails were failing but I wasn't sure why, so adding in an asynchronous call has helped me detect why.

In your code, you need to have the `AddHandler`, so as you've written in your example:

```
Try
    AddHandler Smtp_Server.SendCompleted, AddressOf sendComplete
Catch ex As Exception
    silentErrorLog(ex)
End Try
```

Then, the part that you're missing, you need to put something along the lines of

```
Dim userState As Object = e_mail
Smtp_Server.SendAsync(e_mail, userState)
```

This way, your `sendComplete` subroutine will pick up whether `e_mail` has had any issues or not and can complete the `If e.Error IsNot Nothing` part of the code.

For more information on this, see [this site](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.6.aspx).

Comment: It's worked, it does call the `sendComplete` code, but the email always fails to send. Changing it back to just `Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)` works, so not sure what is going wrong here?

Comment: @Harambe There must be something rooted in a bit deeper, as far as I'm aware this has worked fine for me without too many other differences.